# Order of join in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

My hibernate criteria generates below query but i need inner join as a first join in my query.

Current Query :-

```
select
        count(*) as y0_ 
    from
        load this_ 
    left outer join
        load_carrier carrierrel2_ 
            on this_.load_id=carrierrel2_.load_id 
    left outer join
        carrier carrier3_ 
            on carrierrel2_.carrier_id=carrier3_.carrier_id 
    left outer join
        carrier_shipper_relation carriershi4_ 
            on carrier3_.carrier_id=carriershi4_.carrier_id 
            and (
                shipper1_.shipper_id=carriershi4_.shipper_id 
            ) 
    inner join
        shipper shipper1_ 
            on this_.shipper_id=shipper1_.shipper_id
```

Expected Query:-

```
select
        count(*) as y0_ 
    from
        load this_ 
    inner join
        shipper shipper1_ 
            on this_.shipper_id=shipper1_.shipper_id 
    left outer join
        load_carrier carrierrel2_ 
            on this_.load_id=carrierrel2_.load_id 
    left outer join
        carrier carrier3_ 
            on carrierrel2_.carrier_id=carrier3_.carrier_id 
    left outer join
        carrier_shipper_relation carriershi4_ 
            on carrier3_.carrier_id=carriershi4_.carrier_id 
            and (
                shipper1_.shipper_id=carriershi4_.shipper_id 
            )
```

Order of mapping in my java class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="shipper_id")
private Shipper shipper;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "load", fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
private List<LoadCarrierRelation> carriers = new ArrayList<LoadCarrierRelation>();
```

and In my Dao class

```
criteria.createAlias("shipper", "shipper");
criteria.createAlias("carriers", "carrierrelation");
```

How i can change the sequence of join in query.
It can be done by hql but i don't want to change whole implementation of dao layer because it contain lot of other mapping also.

Comment: There isn't a documented way to control the way the final query is generated.  You will be better off coding the query yourself to have control over how the joins are included in the query.

Comment: I found an article http://www.javaquery.com/2014/10/how-hibernate-interpret-order-of-join.html, but no success

Comment: That article does not cite any official Hibernate document, a random test to draw conclusions.  As long as there is no specification-driven documentation, these things cannot be trusted because implementations can change between versions.  When correctness and performance need to be guaranteed, it is best to hand-code the query and not leave anything to the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed criteria to HQL Query.

Comment: yes, i have changed my criteria  to hql query but if you have some pointer on changing order of join i would like to know.